# What privilege do you get at 1,000 reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

I just got 1K reputation on the Role-playing Games site, and before I did, I paid very close attention to the fact that this would unlock a  new privilege. However, I now have the privilege, and the network has not alerted me about what this privilege allows me to do. **What privilege do you get at 1,000 reputation?**

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations you are now an established user and you get to see [vote counts](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user).

If you click on a post's score it will expand to show the individual counts of upvotes and downvotes.

You can also create [gallery chat rooms](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/gallery-chat-rooms)

You can see a list of all privileges [via this link](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

Comment: Worth to mention, the user card (popup expanding when hovering over a post author) was once a 1k privilege too, but at some point (few years ago, not very long time) they decided to open it for everyone, probably after making the code behind it more efficient, so if lots of people open the card in same time, server won't crash. (as it's just a useful feature.)

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard "*they decided to open it for everyone, probably after making the code behind it more efficient, so if lots of people open the card in same time, server won't crash. (as it's just a useful feature.)*" it was to facilitate easier way for users to specify their pronouns, if needed, since it's cheap: no new functionality is implemented in this way.

Comment: @VLAZ oh, this also make sense. I didn't mean they added new features to it, just that it was never really a privilege, just a useful feature, same as seeing vote counts.